# Is it possible to deduct language course expenses from taxes in Austria?

Tags: taxes, austria, language-course, tax-deductions

I am living in Austria and I am wondering whether it is possible to deduct the cost of a language course from taxes. I do not have sufficient German language ability to read the Austrian tax code in detail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible. From [bmf.gv.at (Austrian Ministry of Finance)](https://www.bmf.gv.at/steuern/arbeitnehmer-pensionisten/arbeitnehmerveranlagung/abc-der-werbungskosten.html#Sprachkurse)

> Kosten zum Erwerb von Fremdsprachenkenntnissen sind abzugsfähig, wenn
>   man die Sprache im Beruf benötigt (zB als Sekretär, Telefonist,
>   Kellner, Hotelangestellte oder Exportsachbearbeiter). Als Fremdsprache
>   gilt jede von der Muttersprache verschiedene Sprache, gegebenenfalls
>   auch Deutsch. Bei Sprachausbildungen im Ausland werden nur die
>   Kurskosten berücksichtigt, nicht aber die Aufenthalts- und
>   Fahrtkosten.

That means that if you use the foreign language for your job, you can deduct the cost of the language course from taxes. The German language also counts as a foreign language if you're not a native speaker.